# How to set reaction to tapping the notification in react-native?

Tags: javascript, android, firebase, react-native, push-notification

I want the application to open proper view after notification was clicked.

I was trying to set up notificationOnOpenListener, and initializing it in different places.

I have already a working function showing notifications:

```
function showNotification(notification){
   PushNotification.localNotification(notification)
}
```

And this is what I was trying to do:

```
this.notificationOnOpenListener = 
    firebase.notifications().onNotificationOpened((notificationOpen) => {

    testNotification(5)
});
```

where testNotification is just a function calling Alert.alert and ToastAndroid.show so I can see it is working.

react-native-cli: 2.0.1
react-native: 0.55.4
node -v
v8.9.3

I expected the alert to show up when I tap the notification, but nothing happens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution:

```
const notificationOpen = await firebase.notifications().getInitialNotification()
            if (notificationOpen) {
                console.log('Opened notification', notificationOpen)
                this._handleOpenNotification(notificationOpen.notification)
            }

            this.notificationOpenListener = firebase.notifications().onNotificationOpened((notificationOpen) => {
                console.log('Opened notification', notificationOpen)
                this._handleOpenNotification(notificationOpen.notification)
            })
```